# How to navigate to URL in LWC embedded in Flows Salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, salesforce-id, visual-flows, forcenavigatetourl

i am trying to navigate to a URl from LWC component , which is embedded in FLOWS.
I have tried each and every possible to navigate to that URL, but i am not able to, although i have debug and there are no errors , in each of my implementations but still no luck.
I have tried NavigateMixin at first place in LWC to navigate , but that didn't worked.
My last implementation which i have implemented taking reference from official documentation of FLows from here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_finish_override.htm&type=5
this documentation says , create an aura component with "lightning:availableForFlowActions"
and add that aura component as an action like this(Generate Document) below[image]

below is my component code to navigate

**Component Markup**

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction, lightning:availableForFlowActions">
<aura:attribute name="Id" type="String" />
 <aura:attribute name="QueryId" type="String" />
   <aura:attribute name="TemplateGroup" type="String" />
   <aura:attribute name="TemplateId" type="String" />
</aura:component>
```

**Design Resource**

```
<design:component>
 <design:attribute name="Id" label="Record ID" />
 <design:attribute name="QueryId" label="Query ID" />
   <design:attribute name="TemplateGroup" label="Template Group" />
   <design:attribute name="TemplateId" label="Template Id" />
</design:component>
```

**Client-Side Controller**

```
({    invoke : function(component, event, helper) {
// Get the record ID attribute
debugger;
var Id = component.get("v.Id");
var QueryId = component.get("v.QueryId");
var TemplateGroup = component.get("v.TemplateGroup");
var TemplateId = component.get("v.TemplateId");
var Url='/apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer?DefaultPDF=1&APDF=0&FP0=2&ZipFiles=0&DS7=11';
if(Id!=undefined && Id!=""){
    Url=Url+'&Id='+Id;
}
if(QueryId!=undefined && QueryId!=""){
    Url=Url+'&QueryId='+QueryId;
}
if(TemplateGroup!=undefined && TemplateGroup!=""){
    Url=Url+'&TemplateGroup='+TemplateGroup;
}
if(TemplateId!=undefined && TemplateId!=""){
    Url=Url+'&TemplateId='+TemplateId;
}
// Get the Lightning event that opens a record in a new tab
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
console.log('Url___Saeed---->'+Url);
urlEvent.setParams({
    "url": Url
  });
  try{
    urlEvent.fire();
  }catch(ex){
    console.log('------>>>>>'+ex);
  }
  

 }})
```

Each and every line of code is executing, i have debugged and getting every console.
Niether i am getting any errors, but still the navigation is not working at all.

I Dont know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes and it worked for me. Also, it is mentioned in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_finish_override.htm&type=5)  that the local actions that fire **force** or **lightning** events might not work properly when you run the flow from: Flow Builder, Flow detail pages, or list views, Web tabs, Custom buttons and links.

I have created sample flow that captures the attributes and launched it from Lightning Page and it worked!

Aura Component HTML Markup:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction, lightning:availableForFlowScreens, lightning:availableForFlowActions" access="global">
        <aura:attribute name="Id" type="String" access="global"/>
        <aura:attribute name="QueryId" type="String" access="global"/>
        <aura:attribute name="TemplateGroup" type="String" access="global"/>
        <aura:attribute name="TemplateId" type="String" access="global"/>
        <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.invoke}"/>
    </aura:component>
```

Aura Component Controller JS:

```
({
  invoke: function (component, event, helper) {
    var Id = component.get("v.Id");
    var QueryId = component.get("v.QueryId");
    var TemplateGroup = component.get("v.TemplateGroup");
    var TemplateId = component.get("v.TemplateId");
    var Url = "/apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer?DefaultPDF=1&APDF=0&FP0=2&ZipFiles=0&DS7=11";
    if (!$A.util.isEmpty(Id)) {
      Url = Url + "&Id=" + Id;
    }
    if (!$A.util.isEmpty(QueryId)) {
      Url = Url + "&QueryId=" + QueryId;
    }
    if (!$A.util.isEmpty(TemplateGroup)) {
      Url = Url + "&TemplateGroup=" + TemplateGroup;
    }
    if (!$A.util.isEmpty(TemplateId)) {
      Url = Url + "&TemplateId=" + TemplateId;
    }
     
    // Get the Lightning event that opens a record in a new tab
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({ url: Url });
    try {
      urlEvent.fire();
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log("------>>>>>" + ex);
    }
  }
});
```